# How to avoid using "means" in sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a way I can structure the following sentence to avoid using "means"?

> The nature of the model **means** it automatically accounts for all
>   environmental factors such as consumer confidence and interest rates.

I find myself using "means" a lot when writing the following types of sentences.

> The existence of X **means** that Y is the result.

I don't believe there's anything particularly wrong with using 'means' but I'm looking for hopefully a more formal alternative.

*Means* here has a definition like "makes necessary"; Y necessarily follows from X. None of the synonyms given at [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mean) for the verb *mean* fit this definition at all.

Comment: The model inherently accounts for all ...     Y results due to X.  Or Y must result due to the existence of X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method, which involves no rephrasing or restructuring at all, is to just remove **means it** altogether:

> The nature of the model automatically accounts for all environmental factors such as consumer confidence and interest rates.

Using *means it* (or anything synonymous like *indicates* or *signifies*) is just filler in this case—as would be rephrasing the sentence only to add a different word or phrase. All you need to do is give the essential parts of the sentence. This also keeps it simple and in an active voice.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up flipping the sentence around. Instead of writing that one thing implies the next, it felt natural to write that the latter is implied by the former. Essentially the voice is changed from active to passive. When writing prose it is normally advised against using the passive voice, but in this case it can give a more formal feel, and help vary things up.

> All environmental factors, such as consumer confidence and interest
>   rates, are automatically accounted for due to the nature of the model.

Instead of **due to** a simple **by** can also suffice

> All environmental factors, such as consumer confidence and interest
>   rates, are automatically accounted for by the models nature.

You can use **due to** while keeping the active voice as well

> Due to its nature the model will automatically account for all
>   environmental factors such as consumer confidence and interest rates.

and **by** in a dependent clause

> The model will, by its nature, automatically account for all
>   environmental factors such as consumer confidence and interest rates.

In short, rather than just focusing on varying the words, change up the structure as well, it will often necessitate the use of new words anyway.

I also see I've opted for **will account for** (future perfect?) rather than your **accounts for** (present indicative?). That wasn't a conscious choice.